# Why is boto requests truncating my query string?

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, python-requests

When trying to make a request from a lambda using botocore.vendored requests I am finding that my query string is being truncated.

I've tried to build it as a string, dict and even tried to just build an encoded url but they all seem to be truncated after the first query parameter

```py
import base64
import os
import traceback
from urllib.parse import urlencode
from botocore.vendored import requests

ORIGIN = os.environ.get('ORIGIN')

def api_proxy(event, context):

    if event['queryStringParameters']:
        myParams = urlencode(event['queryStringParameters'],'utf-8')

    url = ORIGIN + event['path']

    print("URL: " + url)
    print("Params: " + myParams)

    try:
        if myParams:
            dataRequest = requests.get(url, params=myParams)
        else:
            dataRequest = requests.get(url)
        print("Requested URL: " + dataRequest.url)
    except:
        traceback.print_exc()
```

I am printing three different parts of the process and this is what I am getting:

```
URL: https://{my_domain}/premium/data/DefinedImage/png

Params: minY=47.00&minX=-15.00&maxY=61.00&maxX=5.00&width=1000&RUN=2019-05-30T09%3A00%3A00Z&styles=&FORECAST=%2B0&height=1200

Requested URL: https://{my_domain}/premium/data/DefinedImage/png?minY=47.00
```

I would expect the requested URL to be the full URL with all params at the end but the request.get appears to be truncating my URL at the first ampersand.

Comment: `myParams` should be a dictionary

Comment: I have tried that. The event['queryStringParameters'] is a dictionary and I was originally passing that through. That's where I first encountered the problem and the above is where I am with troubleshooting it.

Answer (score 0):

requests methods accept data as a dictionary or byte string. This is done in Python by beginning a string encoded as bytes with a b, for instance: b"my string"

If passing parameters in as bytes, you may want to use the bytes encoding:

```
urllib.parse.urlencode(event['queryStringParameters'])
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that under the hood of the endpoint I am trying to hit there is a authentication redirect which does not encode the url and as such is truncating the query string.

I discovered this by looking at the dataRequest.history URLs.